# HTML set height of every div with class .row to that of the highest

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make every single div with with the class row have the height of that of the highest, however every single approach at doing this that I've found does not work when I try it. The code I'm using to do this currently is as follows:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
    $('document').ready(function(){
        var maxHeight = 0;
        $(".row").each(function(){
            maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).height());     
        });
        $(".row").height(maxHeight);
    });​
</script>
```

The code for my Div's is as follows:

```
    <div class="col" style="border-style: solid solid none solid;">

        <div class="row">

            <b><p>Description</p></b>

        </div>



        <div class="row">

            <textarea style="width: 99%;" rows="1" name="desc"></textarea>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col">

        <div class="row">

            <b><p>Price of Materials</p></b>

        </div>


        <div class="row">

            <textarea style="width: 99%;" rows="1" name="mcost"></textarea>

        </div>

    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
body
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.col
{
    border-style: solid solid none none;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    width: 14%;
}
.row
{
    border-style: none none solid none;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.row p
{
    margin: 0px;
}
.row form
{
    margin: 0px;
}
```

thanks in advance, looking forward to your answers.

**EDIT: Console output:**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL inventory.php:24
Denying load of chrome-extension://ganlifbpkcplnldliibcbegplfmcfigp/scripts/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.map. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.
```

Comment: `$('document').ready({` should be `$('document').ready(function() {` http://jsfiddle.net/jb5y2/

Comment: That still doesn't fix it

Comment: Did you see the fiddle link I posted? Seems to work for me.

Comment: Strange... it works in the fiddle but not my code...

Comment: Check your console for errors and step through the code or add console output to see where things are going wrong.

Comment: FYI, it should be `$(document)` not `$('document')`

Comment: @ProgrammingTurtle When I copy/paste your code directly to jsfiddle, there's a weird character at the end of the script that shows up as a red dot... that could be what the error is referring to. http://jsfiddle.net/9WYm3/

Comment: Oh well, it's fixed now thanks to @Paulie_D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var highestBox = 0;
        $('.wrapper .eqheight').each(function(){  
                if($(this).height() > highestBox){  
                highestBox = $(this).height();  
        }
    });    
    $('.wrapper .eqheight').height(highestBox);

});
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/60623c14d6b54292c3e44a238e22fd21)

Also, this might be useful: http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/#.UxywP_l_uSq

Comment: How is this different?

Comment: Seems from the comments to the OP that this isn't a JS/JQ issue at all. There's always more than one way I guess. :) Good Luck.